# Чтение zip/rar архива посредством javascript

Tags: javascript

Допустим, сайт с музыкальными альбомами. Каждый альбом весит от 300 мб. И альбомы нужно воспроизводить на сайте в плеере. Типа предпрослушки перед скачиванием альбома. Какие средства тогда лучше использовать?
Только js. php - нет.

Comment: @Сергей Власов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Решение [есть](http://gildas-lormeau.github.com/zip.js/), осталось выяснить на сколько оно вам подходящее.

Comment: да, подходит. огромное спасибо...

Comment: "Нельзя голосовать за/против свое сообщение.
Загляните в справку." - Печаль(

--------------------------------------------

Пожалйста.